# Where is the "password=" method being called in my aplication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm stuck in a Ruby on Rails tutorial at [this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users?version=3.2#fnref:6.15) point. I went through the [`has_secure_password`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb?version=3.2#) class definition and I cant figure out in which part of the application is the `password=` method being called? I didn't call it explicitly anywhere in our tutorial but the when I enter:

```
User.create{blah blah}
```

into the Rails console it automatically encrypts the password and adds it to the `password_digest` column!

I've been unable to Google this because of the `=` sign in the method name, so please help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relevant line is:

```
@user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", 
             password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
```

When ActiveRecord model classes receives `new` or `create` with an options hash, they transform the hash keys into method names and call `#{method_name}=` on the newly generated model.

This allows for the controller pattern (or anti-pattern depending on your view)

```
User.new(params)
```